# Non-blocking/async URL fetching in Tornado request

Tags: python, tornado

I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere; I've looked around and haven't found a definitive answer.

I'd like to use Tornado to accept an HTTP request with querystring parameters, use those params to call a NOAA web service to fetch weather data, process/parse the NOAA response, then return the final data to the user.

I'm looking at Tornado because I can't count on the latency or availability of the web service request and I need the calls to be non-blocking. (otherwise I'd just use Django)

I also want to make sure I can set an appropriate timeout on the NOAA request so I can give up as necessary.

*Note: I'm also open to using Twisted, though it seems to have a much steeper learning curve and my needs feel pretty simple. (I would do this in Node.js, but I'm much more comfortable handling the parsing requirements in Python)*

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help point me in the right direction.

I will open-source the server process once finished and credit anyone who contributes examples or RTFM links to the appropriate documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I've extracted code sample from my project. It's not perfect, but it gives an idea how to use Tornadp's AsyncHTTPClient

```
@tornado.gen.engine
def async_request(self, callback, server_url, method=u'GET', body=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Make async request to server
    :param callback: callback to pass results
    :param server_url: path to required API
    :param method: HTTP method to use, default - GET
    :param body: HTTP request body for POST request, default - None
    :return: None
    """
    args = {}

    if kwargs:
        args.update(kwargs)

    url = '%s?%s' % (server_url, urlencode(args))
    request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url, method, body=body)

    http = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http.fetch, request)

    if response.error:
        logging.warning("Error response %s fetching %s", response.error, response.request.url)
        callback(None)
        return
    data = tornado.escape.json_decode(response.body) if response else None
    callback(data)
```